# catch error of make on an expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I am writing an expect script to do make (compile). It's a multi step script and I try to catch the error and stop the script if there is any.
Here is a sample:

```
set BLD_PASS 1
set BLD_PASS [catch {exp_send "make buildXYZ\r"} output]
expect {
  folder] {
    if { $BLD_PASS == "0" } {
       send_user "Build passed on XYZ \n\n"
    } else {
        send_user "Build failed on XYZ\n\n"
        exit
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is I always get BLD_PASS as 0 even when there is real failure.
As I see, the set command gets executed and the BLD_PASS gets the value immediately though the 'make' takes minutes to finish. So, it doesnt look like it's really getting the output of make.

I have verified 'make' outputting the right return code by using it in a bash script.

Could anyone please help me to solve this problem ? Appreciate your help.
Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You can't get the exit status from remote commands like that. You have to do painful stuff like `send "echo \$?\r"` and parse the output. A better strategy is to look for error messages, or the lack thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working is that the `send` itself is succeeding: it sent the message to the other end. It just didn't get the result back yet. It might be easiest to do this by asking the other side to report the exit status and then listen for that.

```
send "make buildXYZ; echo FROGBARGLE_\$?_BARGLEFROG\r"
expect {
    -re {FROGBARGLE_([^\s_]+)_BARGLEFROG} {
        puts "exit code was $expect_out(1,string)"
    }
}
```

There are fancier ways of tracking this sort of thing (and `FROGBARGLE_…_BARGLEFROG` is perhaps a bit *too* arbitrary; I picked it to be something really unlikely to occur in `make` output) but this sort of thing in general is the way you do it when working remotely: you have to tell the other side to tell you what happened.